# Taking pictures of lamps or chandelier

Tags: lighting

So when I take pictures of lamps or any kind of lighting on a house. I get this white-out around the fixture. I would like to know what setting or what i need to do to be able to "see the bulb" without having the white out effect. 
Not sure if this makes sense or not , but...

Thank you
Michael ALlen

Comment: Hey Michael - what camera are you using and how familiar are you with exposure (shutter speed, aperture, ISO)?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach typically involves turning off or dimming the lights and lighting the room externally so that you get more even lighting for the whole scene.

Alternatively, it may be possible to (shoot RAW and) underexpose and pull the highlights and push the shadows enough to avoid blowing out the lights and the area around them too much.  However, this often results in odd looking photos.